# Counting values where 2 columns are meet a criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to count the amount of times a person (Name) appears with the answer yes or no in excel. Here is what my table basically looks like

```
Name  | Answer
Greg  |  YES
Steve |  YES
Jim   |  NO
Greg  |  NO
Greg  |  YES
Steve |  NO
```

So I want to be able to count the amount of times Greg responded 'YES' and 'NO'. So I should be getting 'YES' 2 times.

I've tried `vlookups` and `countif` but I'm not really sure how to combine the 2 columns to get a count or when one equals the other. Can anyone help me with this?

I've also tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="Greg")*(B2:B6="YES"))
```

But I get the error `"Range has no entry corresponding to this cell"`

Comment: Your `SUMPRODUCT` formula is working for me. It correctly outputs the result as 2.

Comment: I'm also using Google docs, does it not work correctly in that? edit: just tried it in excel 2010 and works fine, but not in Google docs. Any way around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm also using Google docs

If you are using google-spreadsheets, try this one:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="Greg")*(B2:B6="YES")))`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `COUNTIFS`

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A7, "Greg", B2:B7, "YES")`